# Speeding up $.mobile.changePage method

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", myPage);
```

to navigate to pages in JQM 1.4.0 and I have noticed that this method uses about 70ms-110ms to execute, somehow this is to much in my humble opinion, so I wonder is there a way to speed up this.
And **transition** is set to **"none"** in **mobileinit** event handler.

```
 $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
 $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = "none";
```

In my specific example I am sending complete jqm page from server, page has **header**,**footer**(with navigation) and as **content** I have **listview widget** with 21 item with icons and data-filter='true' .

- The size of page in JQM 1.4.0 is 9,637kB( 1,0kB gzip) and it takes in
  average 102.1ms (10 mesurment) to pageChange,
- In other case I tested the same staff with JQM 1.3.1 page size
  9,637kB(1,0kB gzip) and in average it takes 102.8ms(10 mesurment) to
  pageChange  .

So results are more or less the same . I need less time to go to server and grab data, than to render page via $.mobile.changePage method :(. And this is tested on desktop browser, mobile browsers are probably event more slower with JS.

I use console.time('start') and console.timeEnd('start') to mesure time mostly in firefox(desktop) browser.

**EDIT**:

```
..
..
$.mobile.loading("show"); 
 getHomePageUI().always(function (data) {//AJAX CALL
        $.mobile.loading("hide");

        if (data.d != null) {

            var homePage = $(data.d);
            homePage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);

            console.time('home1');
            $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", homePage);
            console.timeEnd('home1');

        }
        else {
            MyApp.DisplayErrorMsg("Error calling service!!");
        }
    });
..
..
```

@Giovanni I have updated code.

Comment: Could you please clarify when you invoke console.time('start') and console.timeEnd('start'), exactly?

Comment: you can load pages before moving to them `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "page.html")` and then `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "page.html");`